# Fluent NHibernate Oracle function

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, orm

I'm currently using Fluent NHibernate ORM and trying to call oracle function `fu_GetUserGrant`. I have tried the code below:

```
        var dbCommand = session.Connection.CreateCommand();

        dbCommand.CommandText = "select fu_GetUserGrant(@grantId) from dual;";
        dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        var param = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        {
            param.Value = grantId;
            param.DbType = DbType.StringFixedLength;
            param.Size = 200;
            param.ParameterName = "@grantId";
        }

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

        var result = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return long.Parse(result.ToString());
```

And getting exception - `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-00936: missing expression`

After several hours of failure I tried another approach:

```
var c = session.
        CreateQuery("select fu_GetUserGrant(:grantId) from dual;")
       .SetParameter("grantId", grantId).UniqueResult<int>();
```

and getting exception - `NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException : dual is not mapped [select fu_GetUserGrant(:grantId) from dual;]`

any ideas guys? When i retrieve same function from MSSQL it works fine (of course I use different sql query because of MSSQL.)

Answer (score 0):

At first sample you are using SQL query and in second HQL query. In HQL query there is no dual of course. So what you should do is in SQL using ":" instead "@"

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "select fu_GetUserGrant(:grantId) from dual;"
```

Comment: Firs of all, thanks for helping out. I tried replace '@' with ':' and received same exception - `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-00936: missing expression`. Then i tried just hardcode value in commandText - `dbCommand.CommandText = "select fu_GetUserGrant('*') from dual;"` but same exception appeared.

Comment: Sorry it was only first shot, i am not using such calls in my NHibernate mapping, instead i am registering my functions in custom `Dialect` via `RegisterFunction` to avoid direct Oracle usage and to abstract sql function calls.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find answer to my problem.

To call oracle function i used code bellow:

```
        var dbCommand = session.Connection.CreateCommand();

        dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        dbCommand.CommandText = "fu_GetUserGrant";

        var returnValue = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        {
            returnValue.ParameterName = "Return_Value";
            returnValue.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
            returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        }

        var grantIdParam = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        {
            grantIdParam.Value = grantId;
            grantIdParam.DbType = DbType.StringFixedLength;
            grantIdParam.Size = 200;
            grantIdParam.ParameterName = "m_In_GrantId";
            grantIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(grantIdParam);

        dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

        return long.Parse(returnValue.Value.ToString());
```

What i learned is that, you can call oracle functions through `CommandType.StoredProcedure;` if you specify where will be put return value from the function, in this case was - `var returnValue ...`